# Adding custom fields to build.properties generated by buildnumber-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, version-control, buildnumber-maven-plugin

I am using the [`buildnumber-maven-plugin`](http://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/) to include various version parameters in my WAR artifact to be visible on the page. In my `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>create-buildmeta</id>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>create-metadata</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <doCheck>false</doCheck>
      <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
      <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

That produces a build.properties that looks something like:

```
#Created by build system. Do not modify
#Fri Jan 05 17:10:02 EST 2018
version=2.1.0-SNAPSHOT
revision=1234
name=myApp
timestamp=1515190202388
```

I would like to include some more fields from my `svn info` in the file, like the last user who made a change to the branch etc. Is there a way to configure that and how?

Comment: duplicate ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654572/how-to-get-revision-number-from-subversion-using-maven

Comment: No because the revision number is there already by default. I need to overload the defaults and add more

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not easily possible with `buildnumber-maven-plugin` As you can see from the [source code](https://github.com/mojohaus/buildnumber-maven-plugin/blob/buildnumber-maven-plugin-1.4/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/build/CreateMetadataMojo.java#L184), only the four properties you already mentioned are generated by default:

```
version=2.1.0-SNAPSHOT
revision=1234
name=myApp
timestamp=1515190202388
```

The only way I could imagine to achieve your goal using `buildnumber-maven-plugin` is to execute svn and store the information needed in a property (in the example `last.changed.user`), which you can insert into the configuration as below

```
<configuration>
    <doCheck>false</doCheck>
    <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</outputDirectory>
    <properties>
        <user>${last.changed.user}</user>
    </properties>
</configuration>
```

This produces an additional property, giving a result like this:

```
version=2.1.0-SNAPSHOT
revision=1234
name=myApp
user=someUser
timestamp=1515190202388
```

Unfortunately, I don't know enough about maven's svn integration to give you an example how to store the information you need in an property.

Comment: do you know if there is a better plugin to do this?

Comment: I have no idea, sorry